# Better way to make the shopping cart table with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

So I created a database table called 'cart' and I was originally going to make it more easier by having the 'cartID', one of the fields to auto increment when a user added another item to the cart. However, I realized that as more items are going to be added for that one single cart, I am bound to have so many rows of records. Is there any easier way to go about displaying the information from one cart?

Here is a sample outline of my 'cart' table:

```
cartID | memberID | itemID | shopID | cartQuant | cartDetail |     added
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 |        1 |      1 |      1 |        13 |   Size: XS | 3/12/2018
     2 |        1 |      2 |      1 |         2 |   Size: XL | 3/12/2018
...
```

As you can see, the 'cartID' contains items added to a cart by the 'memberID' of 1. However, it would be way better if the 'cartID' is like the 'orderID' I have on my 'transactions' table so that the order knows which cart it is looking at. Also, the 'shopID' is there to locate the item better (like sorting) so that I display all the 'shopID's first. I did that with ORDER BY shopID.

Any help would be appreciated, I am just looking for a more efficient way of displaying and organizing the cart items.

Comment: Carts can contain items from several shops?

Comment: Is it an intentional choice to store a shopping cart in your database? Have you considered the alternatives? Or is your 'shopping cart' in reality a 'completed order' which just has the wrong name?

Comment: Please share more details. How do you classify any "better way"? What have you tried to reach that? And how is this question related to PHP?

Answer (score 7):

Lately I figured out one of the best ways to manage carts, customers and your products on your cart.

So you will need something like 5 tables. The first table is your customer table:

```
customerID | customerName | customerEmail | ....
-------------------------------------------------
INT (INCR) | VARCHAR(200) | VARCHAR (200) | ....
```

Second you have the shop table with your shops:

```
shopID    | shopName | etc....
----------------------------
INT (INCR)| VARCHAR  | etc ....
```

Then you have the products table with all the products you have available:

```
productID | productName | ProductDescription | etc....
------------------------------------------------------
INT (INCR)| VARCHAR .   | TEXT               | etc...
```

The cart table is very short, but can be expanded very easily till it fits your needs:

```
cartID    | customerID              | DatePlaced
------------------------------------------------
INT (INCR)| INT (From customerTable)| DATETIME
```

So now you are not really addding the products to the cart table directly, you will need a table with the products of the cart. The CartDetail table:

```
cartDetailID   | cartID | shopID | productID | Quantity | dateAdd
----------------------------------------------------------------
INT (INCREMENT)| INT    | INT    | INT       | INT      | DATETIME
```

The cartID here can be repeated and your table will look like this:

```
 cartDetailID   | cartID | shopID | productID | Quantity | dateAdd
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 0              | 15     | 1      | 253       | 3        | 2018-08-03 09:43:17
 1              | 15     | 1      | 255       | 1        | 2018-08-03 09:43:17
```

All you need to do is then form a query that binds all these tables together and get the correct values of all the tables. Making your database like this gives you enough space to expand it, even for different languages and different shops. Hope this helps a bit

Comment: This not helps a bit, it helps much.
Thank you for the solution.

Comment: In case you reach thousands of orders, your cart table grows big time, without a way to clean this table, you have to index it to make it fast for searching, because users may add items to cart but dont checkout.

Comment: does anyone know or can infer the reasoning that `dateAdd` is saved in the table CartDetail?

Comment: @the_mackster It's been years, so I can't exactly say the reason why dateAdd is saved in the detail table. The way I'm looking at it now I don't think it's even worth storing the value.

Answer (score 1):

An easier (yet sort of complex) way to approach this in order to lessen your records on your cart table is readjusting the structure to the below:

```
cartID | memberID | cartDetail
---------------------------------------------------
1      | 1        | 1-1-13-Size: XS, 1-2-2-Size: XL
```

Now you only have 1 cartID and the items and item details (shopID, itemID, cartQuant, cartDetail) all belong to that memberID. All you would need to do is try exploding all the contents of the cartDetail with the `explode()` method in php.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE memberID = '$memberID'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);
$field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$cartID = $field['cartID'];
$cartDetail = $field['cartDetail'];
// check that cart and explode its contents to retrieve cart items based on ','
if($cartDetail != null || $cartDetail != "") {
    // if cart contains ','
    if(strpos($cartDetail, ',')) {
        $cartArray = explode(',', $cartDetail);
        $cartitems = sizeof($cartArray);
    }
    else {
        $cartArray = array();
        $cartArray[0] = $cartDetail;
        $cartitems = 1;
    }
}
else { $cartitems = 0; }
```

The exploded array would print out as of follows:

```
echo cartArray[0]; // 1-1-13-Size: XS
echo cartArray[1]; // 1-2-2-Size: XL
```

But then, you'd want to work with the individual values of each element in the array. Use a loop to print out the exploded contents of the smaller array for this.

```
// for loop here to go through every single element with i as counting
    $currentItem = explode('-', $cartArray[$i]);
    // 0 = shopID, 1 = itemID, 2 = cartQuant, 3 = cartDetail
    $shopID = $currentItem[0];
    $itemID = $currentItem[1];
    $cartQuant = $currentItem[2];
    $cartDetail = $currentItem[3];
```

You'd want to display this right away since it is in a loop for that index.

To display the contents of a cart, use the `explode()` function to print out. In case you are trying to add a new item to the shopping cart, you will not need the function and all you need is retrieve the value from MySQL with an SQL statement and query, fetch the "cartDetail" and save it to a temporary string like `$tempStr`. Then you can add the new elements into it with `$tempStr = $tempStr."1-3-8-Size: M";`.

Also, I erased your "added" field so that you can use reverse array using `array_reverse()` to display the newest items appended to the existing cart (this you have to use `explode()` again).

Answer (score 0):

you should use Database relations in order to make it perfect

you need to create a table for user, products, cart, cart_items

each one has relation to the other, means that

- "cart" table has *user_id* relation with "user" table
- "cart_items" has *cart_id* relation with "cart" table
- "cart_items" has *product_id* relation with "product" table

so now you can add as much as you want to cart using cart_items table with adding the product to it and refer it to which cart in cart table , and the cart refers to the user who owns it .

Final Tables Will be Like This,

[Cart Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdIOy.png)

[Cart_Item Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ0RE.png)